# NSTimer for UITableviewcell similar to World Clock app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nstimer

I would like to build a few simple countdown timers in a UITableview. I noticed the World Clock app has animated clocks in each of it's rows. What is the best method to firing an NSTimer to update each table row? Can a single timer be run that updates all cells or should I have a custom view subclass with built in timer that is added to each row?

I am just trying to get a proper course of action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One timer is sufficient. When it fires, ask the table view for the visible cells and update them one by one. You could also just call `reloadData` when the timer fires but depending on how you draw your cells you might do more work than necessary and you cannot use animations.

Answer (score 3):

Just know that you need to schedule the timer to fire more than once a second. NSTimer isn't a precision device--you're scheduling it for the next available processor slot after the time duration you specify. So a 1 second NSTimer WON'T fire in exactly a second, and can actually accumulate quite a lot of error over time. You want it to come alive several times a second, look at the current time, notice when a second has passed, and do the UI/data updates appropriate to that fact.