# How to show a clock at top of UITableView that constantly updates?

Tags: uitableview, ios4, uiview, xamarin.ios, nstimer

My users enter time information and I need to show local and UTC clocks (digital) at the top of the screen for them to reference.  How can I do this and have it update every second or few seconds?  I can add a header view or text to a section header/footer but I'm not sure how to refresh it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `NSTimer` as suggested in the question's tags - see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805668/nstimer-for-uitableviewcell-similar-to-world-clock-app).